# How to set up a global CustomLog on Apache2 for every virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, logging, web-hosting, file-descriptors

Actually I got some issue with `file descriptors` on **Debian Wheezy** with **3.2.13 kernel** and **Apache/2.2.16**.

I would like to reduce this limit, actually each `virtualhost` got a `CustomLog` and an `ErrorLog`, I want to set up only one `CustomLog` and one `ErrorLog` for all virtualhost.

Is it possible to define one time, a global `CustomLog` on `apache2` for every `virtualhost` ?

I tried `CustomLog` on my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but I got no entry.

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test.global.log global_combined
```

Some documentation about this limit :
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/fd-limits.html

If someone got any clue, it'll help me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to also remove the `CustomLog` and `ErrorLog` directives from the virtual host's configuration, otherwise it'll be logged via the virtual host's log files.
That said, how many virtual hosts are you running? You should be able to increase the fd limit to accommodate the number of virtual hosts you're running. Try apache's documentation example on this:

```
ulimit -S -n 100
```

And adjust the "100" according to your needs.

Comment: I already set up my ulimit before starting apache2. It works, I can handle over 1024 files openned.
Actualy I got nearly 3k files opened :
    ps -A x |grep apache | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I '{}' ls /proc/{}/fd  | wc -l
2964
Now I would like to use just one file for all my log, but I don't know how to set up this custom log on my apache2 configuration.
Actually Im using fastcgi module + 1 customlog + 1 errorlog per virtualhost, I got over 370 vhosts.

Comment: Did you try removing the `CustomLog` and `ErrorLog` directives from the `<VirtualHost>` blocks, while still keeping the global ones that you created?
Aside from the actual number being "big", does the high open file count actually bring you any issues? I'd expect you to be able to handle much more than 3k. By default, we usually set our limit to 65535 though we don't use nearly that much.